# How do I remove non-numerical strings in the two first part of this HTML

Tags: jquery

Im trying to remove ALMOST all non-numerical characters in my HTML below -and made some success with the script below. My problem is though - how do I target the first part of the string, the words "items:"? At the same time I need to keep the currency symbol.

My HTML:

```
<dl>
 <dt><span>items: <em class="minicart"></em><em id="headercartqty">4 items</em></span><span><em id="headercartsum">€1,375</em></span></dt>
 <dd></dd>
</dl>
```

How I want it to be:

```
<dl>
 <dt><span><em class="minicart"></em><em id="headercartqty">4</em></span><span><em id="headercartsum">€1,375</em></span></dt>
 <dd></dd>
</dl>
```

Script:

I tried this which fixes one part of the question:

```
$('em#headercartqty').text(function(_,xText){
return xText.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate first span element like below,

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var firstPart = $($("dt span")[0]).text();
      firstPart = firstPart.replace(/\D/g,'');
      $($("dt span")[0]).text(firstPart); 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl>
 <dt><span>items: <em class="minicart"></em><em id="headercartqty">4 items</em></span><span><em id="headercartsum">€1,375</em></span></dt>
 <dd></dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Well The script I pasted work on the em element. But the biggest problem is to remove the string items: before the span tag.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that. Can't you wrap it by another span tag and simply remove its text?

Comment: No unfortunaly I have no control over the html. I can use jquery or vanilla Js to manipulate it though. Would like to remove the string without changing the html though, if possible. If not i guess  i need to wrap it.

Comment: The string is also dynamic - so target it by exact match for wrapping in divs isn't a good solution - so its a brainticle this one.

Comment: hmm. that did not work for me - I clearly see it works in your code snippet though. strange